# UIPopoverController Bizarre behaviour

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uipopovercontroller

Today, while understanding and tweaking my popover controller I got very bizarre behaviour. So I have decided to make sample demo.

Below is my demo.

Normal iPad application with navigation controller and 2 child views inside that.

In `viewWillAppear` of Rootview of navigation I wrote

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(200.0, 400.0)]
```

and in 2nd child's `viewWillAppear` (of course place one button to call second child)

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
```

Nothing happen to popover. It's as it was. Now I have made slight modification as below,

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(500.0, 200.0)];
```

then only width get change. This is more bizarre, either both width and height should get change or none of them.

I am very confused with this behaviour.

(I am not using `setContentSizeForViewInPopover` as this method is deprecated from iOS 7)

Any suggestion / help appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I increase popover content size for both width and height then both are working as expected. Apparently as I mention, if I decrease content size it remain as it was. If 2nd child has small content size popover content remain as it was, while if we come back to root view (by pressing back) then provided width always get set in popover i.e. if i give width 10 then it become 10 and if I give width 700 it becomes 700. But this only happened for root view and only for width of that view. Height issue/mis behaviour remain as it is.

Comment: It's hard to tell because you write so unclearly, but this _may_ be the same bug discussed in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch22.html#_configuring_and_displaying_a_popover "If a popover’s contentViewController is a UINavigationController, and a view controller is pushed onto or popped off of its stack, then if the current view controller’s contentSizeForViewInPopover differs from that of the previously displayed view controller, ... the popover’s width will change to match the new width, but the popover’s height will change only if the new height is taller"